# A JavaScript Error Occurred in the main process

Tags: angular, electron

I am having a problem running my angular-electron desktop app after successfully building the .exe file on Windows using this CLI Command:

```
npm run electron:windows
```

I got the error

> Javascript error occurred in the main process
>   Uncaught Exception:
>   Error: Cannot find module './src/app/models/user.model'

I could not found any solution on the github repo: https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron

main.ts   file

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, screen, ipcMain } from 'electron';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';
import { createConnection, getConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './src/app/models/user.model';
```

How do I set the path to the user.model.ts file located at src/app/models/user.model so that electron can find it when the app is build for release.

NOTE: everything works fine during development.

Comment: That's not how you mix angular with Electron, you need your workflow to COMPILE the angular app into its "index.html, main.js, vendor.js, etc" thing and then load THAT inside Electron. Your inner Angular code doesn't mix with Electron's "boot-up", refer to this tutorial:
https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-desktop-electron/

Comment: I followed the tutorial but couldn't figure out the right way to link my TypeORM Models to the main.ts file. Can you please give me a code sample of how to do that?

Comment: @user3867365 I'm having the exact same problem, how did you solve it?

Comment: @jeannuel 
Create a folder (e.g `typeormmodels`) in the root directory of your project.
In the `main.ts` file, import your models like so: 
`import { User } from './typeormmodels/user.model';`